# Create FreeXL rpm for CentOS 7: spec file?

Tags: build, compilation, installation, rpm, make-install

I'm trying to build a spec file to create rpm for FreeXL con CentOS 7.

If I try to execute these steps manually

```
tar xzf freexl-1.0.2.tar.gz
cd freexl-1.0.2

export MAKEFLAGS='-j2'

./configure --prefix=/usr/local && make && make install
```

all works fine I can see under /usr/local/..... the files aboout FreeXL.

I've tried to "translate" these steps in a spec file ... here you are it

```
#
# spec file for package freexl
#
# Copyright (c) 2015 SUSE LINUX GmbH, Nuernberg, Germany.
#
# All modifications and additions to the file contributed by third parties
# remain the property of their copyright owners, unless otherwise agreed
# upon. The license for this file, and modifications and additions to the
# file, is the same license as for the pristine package itself (unless the
# license for the pristine package is not an Open Source License, in which
# case the license is the MIT License). An "Open Source License" is a
# license that conforms to the Open Source Definition (Version 1.9)
# published by the Open Source Initiative.

%define libname lib%{name}1
Name:           freexl
Version:        1.0.2
Release:        1.my
Summary:        Library to extract valid data from within an Excel
License:        MPL-1.1 or GPL-2.0+ or LGPL-2.1+
Group:          Development/Libraries/C and C++
Url:            https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/freexl/index
Source:         http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/%{name}-%{version}.tar.gz
BuildRequires:  gcc-c++
BuildRoot:      %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-build

%description
FreeXL is an open source library to extract valid data from within an Excel (.xls) spreadsheet.

%package -n %{libname}
Summary:        Shared library for FreeXL
Group:          System/Libraries

%description -n %{libname}
FreeXL is an open source library to extract valid data from within an Excel (.xls) spreadsheet.

%package devel
Summary:        Development files for %{name}
Group:          Development/Libraries/C and C++
Requires:       %{libname} = %{version}
Requires:       glibc-devel

%description devel
This package contains all necessary include files and libraries needed
to compile and develop applications that use libspatialite.

#redefine path ...
%define _bindir /usr/local

%prep
%setup -q

%build

%configure

%install
./configure --prefix=%_bindir && make && make install

%changelog
```

I obtain my freexl-debuginfo-1.0.2-1.csi.x86_64.rpm file but when I try to install it nothing is installed (and no errors are shown during installation ....

I think that probably there are some errors in my spec file ...... any suggestions / examples?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved: the problem was that my spec file was not complete ....

Here you're a correct spec file that works fine ....

https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file/openSUSE:Factory/freexl/freexl.spec?expand=1

It works for CentOS 7 too!